# Generically providing a setter for a Decorated object that is stored in an array

Tags: java, generics

I'm probably going about this in the most complicated way, but I'm hoping what I'm trying to do makes sense here.

Suppose I have some set of *unrelated, generated* classes and I want to `Decorate` them to create some kind of common API.  So something like:

```
public abstract class GeneratedDecorator<T> {
    private T generated;

    public T getGenerated() { return generated; }
    public void setGenerated(T generated) { this.generated = generated; }

    public abstract String getString();

    public static class ClassA extends GeneratedDecorator<GeneratedClassA> {
        @Override
        public String getString() { return getGenerated().getThisString(); }
    }

    public static class ClassB extends GeneratedDecorator<GeneratedClassB> {
        @Override
        public String getString() { return getGenerated().getADifferentString(); }
    }

}
```

Now, to use this new fancy class I just say:

```
GeneratedDecorator.ClassA a = new GeneratedDecorator.ClassA();
a.setGenerated(myGeneratedInstanceA);
a.getString();
```

Ok so far so-so ... but now I want to manage an array of these `Decorators`.

So let's try:

```
public abstract class DecoratorBundle<T extends GeneratedDecorator> {
    private static final int MAX_ROWS = 10;

    private T[] bundle;

    DecoratorBundle() { bundle = createBundle(); }

    public String getString(int index) { return bundle[index].getString(); }

    public void setRow(??? generated, int index ) {
        //check index of bundle, if null create a new instance of appropriate type and set bundle[index] = new instance
        //call setGenerated on instance at index
    }

    protected abstract T[] createBundle();

    public static class ClassA extends DecoratorBundle<GeneratedDecorator.ClassA> {
        @Override
        protected GeneratedDecorator.ClassA[] createBundle() {
            return new GeneratedDecorator.ClassA[MAX_ROWS];
        }
    }

    public static class ClassB extends DecoratorBundle<GeneratedDecorator.ClassB> {
        @Override
        protected GeneratedDecorator.ClassB[] createBundle() {
            return new GeneratedDecorator.ClassB[MAX_ROWS];
        }
    }

}
```

Here's where I'm stuck ... I want this `DecoratorBundle` to have a `setRow(??? generated, int index)` where the parameter is of the `GeneratedDecorator`'s type (i.e, `GeneratedClassA` or `GeneratedClassB`).  Seems like type erasure will probably make this impossible, but it would be really nice to have this `DecoratorBundle` class to completely manage it's `bundle` array.  It currently is able to instantiate the array, but I want some way for it to create a new `GeneratedDecorator`-type and assign it in a `setRow` method.

If I'm going about this completely wrong then I would love to hear another idea.

Comment: This I think is a mistake: `DecoratorBundle<T extends GeneratedDecorator>`  The class `GeneratedDecorator` is generic and here you are using the raw type.  Should be something like: `DecoratorBundle<T extends GeneratedDecorator<X>>` and you may need to parameterize both T and X.

Comment: `public void setRow(??? generated, int index ) {` Given my comment above I think you need `public void setRow(GeneratedDecorator<X> generated, int index ) {`

Comment: @AdamSiemion - Sure, this code has a smell, but how else should I implement a Decorator.  I would change a few things about the generated code to make this code potentially unnecessary, but that ship has long since sailed.  If you have any suggestions to voice, I'm all ears.

Comment: @markspace Interesting idea, but the compiler is having trouble resolving `X` in the class declaration.  What am I missing?  Maybe you can flesh out an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Oh, I need to `DecoratorBundle<X,T extends GeneratedDecorator<X>>`  If you make an answer out of your comment I'll happily upvote and approve it.